# Which communities are good creative outlets for software development discussions?

Tags: forum

StackOverflow is wonderful for Q&A style questions, but it is not in anyway a forum for discussing software engineering in general.  Where do you go when you are not looking for a forum that is geared for helping people with problems, but just talking about design and development?

I've considered real life user groups (never been to one before, though).  I don't know if these would be a good answer or not.

PS. I have searched SO quite a bit for a similar thread.  We have tons covering other Q&A and also resource sites, but not any that I could find that are just for discussion.  I've also searched online myself, but its difficult to filter through all of the dead communities that litter the web.  Help me!

Answer (score 1):

http://chipy.org no kidding. We rock. Point being find a local user group in something more specific.